# C++ Why emplacing object in vector segfaults?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, strategy-pattern

I want to create a vector of "Act" objects that contain pointers to either "Eat" or "Drink" dynamically allocated objects. The new objects are being emplaced like so:

```
action_vector.emplace_back(Act::BehaviorType::eat);
```

However, it is seg-faulting and I can't figure out why. I thought that emplace_back would implicitly call the move constructor, not the destructor, but for some reason it is, which (I think) is what is screwing everything up.

Is there any way to successfully create a vector of such objects?

Here is the rest of the code along with its output. Sorry if it's a little verbose, but basically it's just a strategy pattern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IBehavior
{
public:
    IBehavior() = default;
    virtual ~IBehavior() = default;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class Drink : public IBehavior
{
public:
    Drink(): IBehavior() {}
    ~Drink() {}
    void execute() { std::cout << "Drinking" << std::endl; }
};

class Eat : public IBehavior
{
public:
    Eat(): IBehavior() {}
    ~Eat() {}
    void execute() { std::cout << "Eating" << std::endl; }
};


class Act
{
    IBehavior * b;

public:

    enum class BehaviorType { eat = 0, drink = 1 };

    Act() = default;
    ~Act()
    {
        std::cout << "Calling the destructor" << std::endl;
        delete b;
    }
    Act(BehaviorType b_type) { SetBehavior(b_type); }

    Act(Act&& act)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling the move constructor" << std::endl;
        this->b = act.b;
    }


    void SetBehavior(BehaviorType b_type)
    {
        if(b_type == BehaviorType::eat) b = new Eat();
        if(b_type == BehaviorType::drink) b = new Drink();
    }

    void execute() { b->execute(); }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<Act> action_vector;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        action_vector.emplace_back(Act::BehaviorType::eat);
        action_vector[i].execute();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Eating
Calling the move constructor
Calling the destructor
Eating
Calling the move constructor
Calling the move constructor
Calling the destructor
Calling the destructor
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: When a move constructor or move assignment "steals" a single-use resource, it must not leave it in the original object to be reaped by the destructor.  So in this case, after copying pointer `b` into `this` (`this->b = act.b`), it should set `act.b = nullptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your move constructor copies `b`, and destructor deletes `b`, so if you move construct an instance then the same pointer value will be deleted twice which has undefined behaviour.

General solution: Use a smart pointer.

---

Another bug: Default constructor leaves `b` uninitialised. When a default constructed object is destroyed, the uninitialised pointer is deleted and behaviour is undefined. Smart pointer fixes this also.

Comment: Does not segfault on a mac, LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2)

Comment: @Gardener well, the behaviour is undefined. It's not guaranteed to segfault.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. However, the issue still remains if I write "this->b = std::move(act.b);" in the move constructor (Is this because the "original" b is still be destructed upon but is now empty?). I probably should be using smart pointers but I really want to fix my intuition w.r.t what's happening with regular pointers first. How would this situation be handled with regular pointers?

Comment: Moving a bare pointer is same as copying the pointer. It solves nothing. You can fix this bug by assigning `act.b = nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks, think I get it, also TIL deleting nullptr is safe.